# How to configure FreeBSD to reject configuration options in the ports tree that have graphical dependencies?

Tags: freebsd, freebsd-ports

I have a couple of personal-use servers on which I would like to prevent the unnecessary installation of X11, Wayland, or any other unnecessary GUI dependencies.  Is there a way to configure my systems to reject changes to `make config` if they would bring in a GUI package as a dependency and say which option was the one that brought in the GUI package(s)?

[This answer seems to give a good starting outline](https://serverfault.com/questions/334934/freebsd-ports-how-can-i-see-all-dependencies-for-a-port-and-all-subdependencie) but doesn't have the "turning on option X in `make config` will bring in X11" specificity.

---

Somewhat related, is there an easy command to uninstall all `X11/*` ports?

Answer (score 0):

You can add to your `/etc/make.conf`

```
OPTIONS_UNSET+=X11 XPM
```

Most ports will build without X11 dependencies by default.
With `make config` you can still override this.